# NullPointerException and data duplication come when sending data to the server

Tags: android, mysql, nullpointerexception

I want to send data to the mysql server from my android application. I have two tables. I used Json format to send data using php scripts. Data is sending, but NullPointerException occur after send the data and crash the application. Sometime  data send two times, means data duplication is happen. But when I test in the localhost using XAMPP everything was fine. This happens when try to send data to remote server using internet.

**This is my java code**

```
public class SelectItem extends AppCompatActivity implements SelectItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private String dealerName, dealerID, repID, orderId, newOrderId, orderIdForItemTable, json_string, numberPickerNumber;
    private static final int TIME_DELAY = 2000;
    private static long back_pressed;
    private RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
    private SelectItemAdapter myRecyclerViewAdapter;
    private CartItemAdapter myCartItemAdapter;
    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder selectItemAdapter;
    private MaterialSuggestionAdapter adapter;
    private JsonParseMaterial jpm;
    private Button bAdd;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private VollySingleton vollySingleton;
    private SQLiteHandler sqLiteHandler;
    private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select_item);

        vollySingleton = VollySingleton.getsInstance();
        requestQueue = vollySingleton.getmRequestQueue();

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.selectedItemRecyclerView);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

        sqLiteHandler = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        myRecyclerViewAdapter = new SelectItemAdapter(this);
        myRecyclerViewAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        myRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        dealerName = DealerListAdapter.getDealerName();
        dealerID = DealerListAdapter.getDealerID();
        repID = DealerListAdapter.getRepID();

        //order number
        orderId = "70000001";

        if (newOrderId == null) {
            newOrderId = orderId;
        }

        bAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);

        bAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount() != 0) {

                    checkOrderNo();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        //textView.setText(dealerName);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(dealerName);

        final AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

        adapter = new MaterialSuggestionAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
        acTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Product result = adapter.getItem(position);
                String newName = result.getMatName().toString();
                String newQty = String.valueOf(result.getMatQuantity());
                String newPCode = result.getMatNo().toString();
                String newPlant = result.getMatPlant().toString();

                if (!newName.equals("")) {

                    if (myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount() > 1) {
                        myRecyclerViewAdapter.add(1, newName, newQty, newPCode, newPlant);

                    } else {
                        myRecyclerViewAdapter.add(0, newName, newQty, newPCode, newPlant);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Product Already in the List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                acTextView.setText("");
            }
        });


    }


    //send items for one order
    private class SendItemAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            //Create JSON string start
            json_string = "{\"sending_items\":[";

            for (int i = 0; i < myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount(); i++) {

                if (myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i) instanceof SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder) {
                    SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder childHolder = (SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder) myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i);
                    numberPickerNumber = childHolder.getQtyNumber();
                }

                //Repeat and loop this until all objects are added (and add try+catch)
                try {
                    JSONObject obj_new = new JSONObject();
                    obj_new.put("order_no", orderIdForItemTable);
                    obj_new.put("items", myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemName(i).toString());
                    obj_new.put("items_no", myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemPCode(i).toString());
                    obj_new.put("plant", myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemPlant(i).toString());
                    obj_new.put("quantity", numberPickerNumber);
                    json_string = json_string + obj_new.toString() + ",";

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            //Close JSON string
            json_string = json_string.substring(0, json_string.length() - 1);
            json_string += "]}";

            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 3500);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 1000);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

            String url = AppConfig.URL_ITEMS_SEND;

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
            try {
                request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json_string.getBytes("UTF8")));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            request.setHeader("json", json_string);
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            Log.i("", "excuting request");
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = client.execute(request);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("HTTP Response", response.getStatusLine().toString());

            try {
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.d("Server Response", responseBody);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            finish();
            Bundle basket = new Bundle();
            basket.putString("dealerName", dealerName);
            basket.putString("orderNo", newOrderId);
            basket.putString("jsonString", json_string);
            Intent intent = new Intent(SelectItem.this, ItemCart.class);
            intent.putExtras(basket);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json_string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sub_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.toolbar_logo) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder item, int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Remove " + position + " : " + item.getItemName(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        myRecyclerViewAdapter.remove(position);
    }

    private void checkOrderNo() {

        showDialog();

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
        final String nowDate = df.format(new Date());

        //final day of the month
        Date today = new Date();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(today);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        Date lastDayOfMonth = calendar.getTime();
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        final String lastDate = sdf.format(lastDayOfMonth);

        Log.d("Last day ", sdf.format(lastDayOfMonth) + " // Today" + nowDate);


        // Tag used to cancel the insert
        String tag_string_req = "req_insert";

        final StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_ITEM_DETAILS_SEND, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                hideDialog();
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    if (jObj.names().get(0).equals("found")) {

                        newOrderId = jObj.getString("found").toString();
                        orderIdForItemTable = newOrderId;

                        new SendItemAsync().execute();

                        Log.d(TAG, "newOrderId: " + newOrderId);
                        Log.d(TAG, "New repID 2 inserted into sqlite: " + newOrderId + " " + nowDate);
                        sqLiteHandler.addItemDetails(newOrderId, repID, dealerID, nowDate, lastDate);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalied Request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Inserting Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("order_no", orderId);
                params.put("repID", repID);
                params.put("dealerID", dealerID);
                params.put("nowDate", nowDate);
                params.put("lastDate", lastDate);

                return params;
            }
        };

        strReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(3500, 0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

**My logCat**

```
04-05 13:08:08.144 11370-11370/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat D/SQLiteHandler: newOrderId: 70000006
04-05 13:08:08.144 11370-11370/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat D/SQLiteHandler: New repID 2 inserted into sqlite: 70000006 2016/04/05 01:08:05

                                                                                             [ 04-05 13:08:08.150 11370:11544 I/         ]
                                                                                             excuting request
04-05 13:08:08.166 11370-11370/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat D/SQLiteHandler: New details inserted into sqlite: 5
04-05 13:08:09.196 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273)
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:860)
04-05 13:08:09.197 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
04-05 13:08:09.198 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
04-05 13:08:09.198 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
04-05 13:08:09.198 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat.SelectItem$SendItemAsync.doInBackground(SelectItem.java:233)
04-05 13:08:09.198 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat.SelectItem$SendItemAsync.doInBackground(SelectItem.java:177)
04-05 13:08:09.198 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
04-05 13:08:09.198 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-05 13:08:09.198 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-05 13:08:09.198 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-05 13:08:09.198 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-05 13:08:09.198 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-05 13:08:09.207 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                                                                              Process: com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat, PID: 11370
                                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'cz.msebera.android.httpclient.StatusLine cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpResponse.getStatusLine()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                  at com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat.SelectItem$SendItemAsync.doInBackground(SelectItem.java:237)
                                                                                                  at com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat.SelectItem$SendItemAsync.doInBackground(SelectItem.java:177)
                                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
04-05 13:08:09.250 11370-11402/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-05 13:08:09.251 11370-11402/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe233fe60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-05 13:13:09.223 11370-11544/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11370 SIG: 9
```

**My PHP script**

```
<?php

require_once 'include/Configg.php';

    $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die("connection failed");
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE,$con) or die("db selection failed");

    $order_no = $repID = $dealerID = $nowDate = $lastDate = "";

    if(isset($_POST['order_no'])){
        $order_no = $_POST['order_no'];
        $repID = $_POST['repID'];
        $dealerID = $_POST['dealerID'];
        $nowDate = $_POST['nowDate'];
        $lastDate = $_POST['lastDate'];
    }

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(order_no) FROM items_details");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    if($row[0] < 70000000){
        $highest_id = 70000000;
    } else{
        $highest_id = $row[0] + '1';
    }
    //$highest_id = $row[0] + '1';

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO items_details(order_no,rep_no,dealer_no,order_date,last_date) VALUES('$highest_id','$repID','$dealerID','$nowDate','$lastDate')");

    $json['found']= $highest_id;    
    echo json_encode($json);



?>
```

**Second script to other table**

```
<?php

require_once 'include/Configg.php';

    $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die("connection failed");
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE,$con) or die("db selection failed");

    $postdata = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
    $data = json_decode($postdata, true);

   if (is_array($data['sending_items'])) {
        foreach ($data['sending_items'] as $record) {
            $order_no = $record['order_no'];
            $items = $record['items'];
            $items_no = $record['items_no'];
            $plant = $record['plant'];
            $quantity = $record['quantity'];

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO item_list(order_no, items, items_no, plant, quantity) VALUES('$order_no', '$items', '$items_no', '$plant', '$quantity')");

      }
   }

echo json_encode($data);
mysql_close($con); 

?>
```

Comment: try increasing the timeout. You are getting a time out error. DefaultHttpClient is deprecated. Use something like org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients or even better use volley. You will saved of many headaches

Comment: ok, I will thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `Response` to `null` here.

```
HttpResponse response = null;
try {
     response = client.execute(request); // trying to execute to get reponse
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace(); // if fails, response remains null.
}
// if successful no problem, if failed you are getting null pointer exception as response is null.
Log.d("HTTP Response", response.getStatusLine().toString());
```

Reason of failure is `SocketTimeoutException` which means your remote server is not reachable. So you should handle this situation and format the code like below:

```
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(request);

            Log.d("HTTP Response", response.getStatusLine().toString());

            try {
               String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.d("Server Response", responseBody);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }                

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
```

On a different note: I noticed that you have include `volley` into your code. Why don't you use to make this network call as `DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated.

Comment: @Dmadushanka, can you also accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Cn you help me with this also please. I didnt find any answer .thank you.      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448630/check-the-item-selected-from-the-autocompletetextview-already-exist-in-the-recyc

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of `try` and `catch` statements in your `doInBackground` that causes this types of errors in your program. When there is something wrong and an `Exception` is thrown you should immediately return from your function.

Here is some suggestion regarding your code:

Change the `AsyncTask` signature to the following:

```
private class SendItemAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
```

In your `doInBackground` function change the behavior of your try and catches like:

```
try {
        JSONObject obj_new = new JSONObject();
        obj_new.put("order_no", orderIdForItemTable);
        obj_new.put("items", myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemName(i).toString());
        obj_new.put("items_no", myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemPCode(i).toString());
        obj_new.put("plant", myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemPlant(i).toString());
        obj_new.put("quantity", numberPickerNumber);
        json_string = json_string + obj_new.toString() + ",";

        } 
catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return new Boolean(false);
}

...

try {
       request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json_string.getBytes("UTF8")));
    } 
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return new Boolean(false);
    }

try {
        response = client.execute(request);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new Boolean(false);
    }

...

try {
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.d("Server Response", responseBody);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return new Boolean(false);
    }
return true;
```

and finally change your `onPostExecute` to handle the error situation:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean noError) {
     if(!noError)
         return;       
     finish();
     Bundle basket = new Bundle();
     basket.putString("dealerName", dealerNam
     ...
```