# Check the Item selected from the AutoCompleteTextView already exist in the RecyclerView

Tags: android, duplicates, android-recyclerview, autocompletetextview

I have AutoCmpleteTextView and RecyclerView in my app. When I searched and selected an item from the AutCompleteTextView it will added to the RecyclerView. It worked very well. But I want to know whether the selected item is already exist in the RecyclerView. Avoid item duplication.

This is my code.

```
final AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

        adapter = new MaterialSuggestionAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
        acTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Product result = adapter.getItem(position);
                String newName = result.getMatName().toString();
                String newQty = String.valueOf(result.getMatQuantity());
                String newPCode = result.getMatNo().toString();
                String newPlant = result.getMatPlant().toString();

                if (!newName.equals("")) {
                    if (myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
                        if (newName != myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemName(position).toString()) {
                            myRecyclerViewAdapter.add(1, newName, newQty, newPCode, newPlant);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Product Already in the List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        myRecyclerViewAdapter.add(0, newName, newQty, newPCode, newPlant);
                        }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalied Item!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                acTextView.setText("");
            }
        });


    }
```

If I changed **position** to **1** in this line 
**if (newName != myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemName(position).toString())**

LogCat give me this error

```
04-06 16:08:01.681 25361-25361/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                              Process: com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat, PID: 25361
                                                                                              java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
                                                                                                  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                                                  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                                                  at com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat.adapters.SelectItemAdapter.getItemName(SelectItemAdapter.java:54)
                                                                                                  at com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat.SelectItem$2.onItemClick(SelectItem.java:166)
                                                                                                  at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:905)
                                                                                                  at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.access$500(AutoCompleteTextView.java:90)
                                                                                                  at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownItemClickListener.onItemClick(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1201)
                                                                                                  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
                                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
                                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
                                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: you have only one item in recylerview, that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: Ok.thankz.but how to find the item is already in the recyclerview or not? Give a toast that item is already in the list

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: yes, it works brother. sorry for the delay. this is new year season for us. thank you very much

Comment: Great. Happy new year. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the comments, if you want to check if the item if present in `RecyclerView` then try to do like this:

```
if (myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
    if (!isPresent(newName, myRecyclerViewAdapter)) {
        myRecyclerViewAdapter.add(1, newName, newQty, newPCode, newPlant);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Product Already in the List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And `isPresent` can be defined like this:

```
private boolean isPresent(String name, MyRecyclerViewAdapter myRecyclerViewAdapter){
    boolean isPresent = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount(); i++){
            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemName(i).toString())){
                isPresent = true;
                break;
            }
    }
    return isPresent;
}
```